# Python - what is the libs subfolder for?

Tags: python, directory, libs

For me, it's located at C:\Python33\libs.

For reference - this is **not** the same folder as C:\Python33\Lib - note the capitalization and lack of an 's'.

On one computer I was working on, I simply dropped a .py file into the libs folder and could import and use it like a library / module (sorry, I don't really know terminology very well), regardless of where the project I was working on is.

However, in trying to duplicate this on another machine, this doesn't work. Attempting to import simply gives a "no module named X" error.

So, clearly I'm misunderstanding the purpose of the libs folder, and how it differs from the Lib folder.

So, what exactly *is* the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you compare libs/ vs. Lib/ you'll notice that the latter is full of *.py files and the former has *.lib files.  Further investigation with a text editor will show that *.py files are human-readable (I hope) and the *.lib files are not.

And that's really the difference.  If you want to know more, the .lib files are static-link libraries, used for building .dlls, C extensions, and all that good stuff.  Head on down the [rabbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library) [hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_link_library) if that interests you.

On to the meat of your question: are you supposed to be able to drop modules in there and be able to import them?  Not really.  That is a side effect of that folder being included in your path.  From the Modules [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - the installation-dependent default.

Various installation methods will modify %PATH% or %PYTHONPATH% so I can't tell you exactly where to look; on my windows box, the python installer modified %PATH% for me, so you should probably look there first.  Notably, my path does *not* include Python33/libs/ so I would not expect it to be there by default.

Comment: Thank you, very clear. Python33/libs/ isn't included in my path either (on either machine). Perhaps I simply dropped a copy into both libs and Lib without realizing it? In any case, you answered my question perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Just looking on mine (Windows 7) /libs appears to be the native code libraries (*.lib) vs the straight python libraries in /Lib. The readme also mentions a configuration flag:

--with-libs='libs': Add 'libs' to the LIBS that the python interpreter
        is linked against.

Which may or may not be set on different installs/platforms.

This isn't really a answer; hopefully someone with a firmer knowledge of it will explain further - was just a bit too much info to squeeze into a comment.