# why python contains libs and lib directories?

Tags: python

It confuses me that python installation contains lib directory with python libs (packages) and secondary similar directory named 'libs' where also contains libs: Libs staticly linked binary files with .lib extension. Why?

Comment: Hi, have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285892/python-what-is-the-libs-subfolder-for

Comment: theAlse, you found similar question, I understand that both directories contains different stuff: python libs and native libs. But from another point of view there are still libs. :-) So I'm confused. :-) And when I'm looking for python lib I always have to think: go to 'lib' or go to 'libs'.. :-)

Comment: Karol, if you hear python libraries, then it (almost) always means Lib (and probably Lib/site-packages)

Comment: theAlse, OK, but when I see python/include which contains C/C++ header files then this is paired with (or should) with python/lib.

Comment: I think that everything which confuses me is the plural form. :-)