# Import file from lib directory?

Tags: python, file, python-import, file-structure

I've been reorganizing my project because there was an issue somewhere, but, as programming always goes, the problem is now 10 times worse and everything is broken.

My current file tree that I am satisfied with is:

```
Amazons AI
  - .git
  - Game_Code
    - __pycache__
    - game.py
  - lib
    - __pycache__
    - __init__.py (empty)
    - motion.py
    - pieceManagement.py
  - tests
    - __pychache__
    - test_game.py
  - README.md
```

My issue is that in `game.py` (in the `Game_Code` folder, I need to import `motion.py` and `pieceManagement.py` (both in the `lib` directory).

I've tried multiple ways to go up a level in the directory, import lib and then everything from that, largely using the suggestions in [Import a file from a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory), but nothing has worked. For reference, I am using Python 3.7.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access `libs` in parent directory of the current file, one can do this:

`sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) + "/libs")`

It adds parent dictory + `/libs` to the sys path where python will know to look for it as described in [Python - what is the libs subfolder for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285892/python-what-is-the-libs-subfolder-for). However, I don't like this solution as it leads to ugly code like this:

```py
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) + "/libs")

from pieceManagement import piece
import motion
```

So I'd still like to find a pythonic way to do it, maybe inline with the import statements. But I know this works (on my machine).

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert But last weekend i wrote some python code with the similar structure and used from folder.file import reference to reflect the folder structure:

```
from lib.motion import classObject as ObjectName 
from lib.pieceManagement import classMethod() as MethodName()
```

Comment: Not quite sure why, but I get the `module not found` err.